# Number of Communities in Leiden Algorithm

Tags: python, networkx, cluster-computing, graph-theory

To approach a combinatorial problem I use [communities detection](https://towardsdatascience.com/community-detection-algorithms-9bd8951e7dae) and need to pre select the number of communities. This is possible in Louvain Method in [communities package](https://pypi.org/project/communities/)

```py
# ! pip install communities

import numpy as np
from communities.algorithms import louvain_method

A = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], 
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

A_sq = np.matmul(A,A.transpose())

nbr_communities = 3
communities, _ = louvain_method(A_sq, nbr_communities)


print("len communities = ", len(communities), "nbr_communities=", nbr_communities)
print(communities,"\n")
for com in communities:
  print(A[list(com)], "\n")
```

I couldn't find such a parameter for Leiden Algorithm in [cdlib](https://cdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/reference.html), or [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.louvain.louvain_communities.html#networkx.algorithms.community.louvain.louvain_communities). Is there an implementation of Leiden that lets select it, or another way to achieve this?